# Create a timetable with HTML

Tags: php, html-table

I want to make a timetable in HTML of my weekly schedule at work. I already have a database that's functioning with hourly slots of where I'm meant to be.

How would I go about making this in HTML? I can create a table in html but how would I exactly go about plotting what I want exactly?

Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to make: 
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to show the structure of your database and/or the structure of the array into which you fetch data.

Comment: You could probably implement something based off of an [open source gantt chart](http://bastianallgeier.com/gantti/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to offer a helpful/direct answer because we don't really know the scheme of your database. If you are wondering how to get information and iterate it into a table, there is a good (albeit dated and poorly styled) tutorial [here](http://phpeasystep.com/mysql/6.html).

To go over what it says quickly, the first thing you want to do is connect to your database. There is a [good article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/?search_index=34) on Nettuts discussing the best practices of accessing a database, but since we're just starting off we can just use the following (I encourage you to revisit the code and use what you learned at Nettuts to write something using PDO):

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Once you've connected, all you need to do is (1) query the database (in this case we're looking for all records in a table):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

And (2) loop through the results using a while loop

```
<table>
<?php
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<td><?php echo $rows['theNameOfYourRow']; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Again, I strongly encourage you to review some of the database best practices tutorials on nettuts, [they have](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql/?search_index=28) a [bunch](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/?search_index=3) of [really good](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/?search_index=12) ones[enter link description here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners/?search_index=20).